# A way of skipping tests in a GWTTestCase

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, gwt

Is there something similar to jUnit's @Ignore annotation for the GWTTestCase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used this API, but it looks like `GWTTestCase extends junit.framework.TestCase`. 
Hence annotations wont be available and you'll have to manually rename your testXX methods to something that doesn't start with 'test'